# Sorting field in Url for Elastic Search

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I am sending a get request to elastic search with sorting fields in the URL query parameters. ES is responding me with 400 bad request error, saying no mapping found for [mysearchtype], This is happening only when there are 0 records. When I have records then the search is fine and I am getting the sorted result

Answer (score 0):

When there are records it works because a dynamic mapping is generated. A solution would be to manually assign a mapping to your type, at index creation for example. Check out [the documentation here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html).

If you don't want to write it yourself, you can use the one dynamically generated :

- insert one record
- take a look at the mapping : `GET index/_mapping`
- delete index
- create index with the previous mapping (cf. doc)